# Paragraph Bundle $content always Showing null in .tpl

Tags: nodes, blocks

I am using the [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) and [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) modules in Drupal.  I have created a paragraph bundle called Section Block, Machine Name: section_block and a custom view name Sectional Landing Page Block that has the Sectional Block as an Item within the view to display this paragraph bundle.

I have a content type with the section block paragraph bundle enabled and I have content entered within this content page.  I also have this view added to a custom Block that I have created.

I have created a .tpl file named:

```
paragraphs-item--section-block.tpl.php
```

Inside of this `.tpl` file I am only trying to `var_dump` the `$content` to see how I can change the markup for this paragraph bundle.  I am getting a empty array for the $content variable.

What are some debugging methods to help solve this issue?